# Where does eclipse.exe come from?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to start a Java application via `.exe` but with the ability to tweak both application arguments and JVM arguments in some `.ini` file. `eclipse.exe` seems to be fitting but I can't seem to figure out where it comes from? Where is the upstream source for it? Can it be customized to run arbitrary application?

Comment: You can use the JNI api call `JNI_CreateJavaVM` to create a JVM from any binary (only one per process, though). So you can easily write a very thin replacement for `java.exe`. I think https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library/win32 is the place where you would find the source for Eclipse specifically.

Comment: The eclipse.exe is used for any Eclipse RCP you build (renamed to whatever you choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, it works great for our Equinox application. One just needs to produce correct `.ini` file. These two wiki pages, and the link to the [sources](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature/library/win32), helped a lot:

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher

The executable is in one of the many `org.eclipse.equinox.executable_root.*` ZIP files, depending on platform. A companion OSGi bundle is necessary. E.g., for Windows it would be `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64*.jar`, extracted in `plugins` directory.